# org-babel SQL How to use SELECT result single result without data cleanup?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have quite a few SQL org-babel functions for fetching various(single record) IDs from the database.

The snippet below works, but is there any way to skip that middle function that converts SQL result to a simple string? My goal here is to DRY this org-mode/org-babel file.

```
#+name: raw-sql-token
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :results value
  SELECT 123 AS token
#+END_SRC

#+name: sql-token
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :var input=raw-sql-token :results value
  (print (nth 0(nth 0 input)))
#+END_SRC

#+HEADER: :var id=sql-token
#+BEGIN_SRC http :pretty
  GET http://localhost:3000/api/items/${id}
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexing on the result table to select the cell you want:

```org
#+HEADER: :var id=raw-sql-token[2,0]
#+BEGIN_SRC http :pretty
  GET http://localhost:3000/api/items/${id}
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: "Indexing variable", got it. Thank you!